# Stacks of physics bodies in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have an `SKScene` which has gravity enabled on the physics world and a `SKSpriteNode` is created every second. The node has a physics body that is the same height but slightly smaller in width than the sprite.

These nodes are created at the top of the scene and fall, due to the gravity of the world, to the bottom of the scene. Each node then falls on top of the node below it.

See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A9ImdZ0Un30 for the effect I have currently achieved.

There are several issues I am encountering with the implementation and I’m fairly lost as to how to start fixing them:-

1. Each node/physics body still appears to be participating in the physics simulation, as can be seen when there are 4+ rows as the effect of a node falling on a column causes the nodes below it to bounce. I want the nodes that have fallen to be static and not be affected by nodes falling on top of them. This additionally causes the FPS to drop as the screen fills up since the physics simulation is calculating gravity on all bodies.
2. Some nodes come to rest at a different Y co-ordinate to other nodes on the same row. This can be seen by the node at row 3, column 2 being slightly higher than the other nodes on the row.
3. On some rows there are gaps between vertically adjacent nodes. To achieve the desired visual effect there should be no gaps. I have tried making the physics body smaller than the node in height but issue 2 still occurs.
4. This is not particularly an issue, but more of a desired feature. I would like to retain the bounce effect of the first or second rows, subsequent rows do not bounce as much, presumably due to the mass of the nodes already in the column absorbing some of the energy of the falling node.

Additionally I’d like to be able to know when a node has came to rest, I have been able to use the didBeginContact: method of `SKPhysicsContactDelegate` but that fires for each collision during a bounce (this can be 2 or 3 times).

**Update**

An additional game mechanic is that as bricks are falling, ones in the column might disappear. This should result in the rest of the column falling down to the next lowest brick and the brick currently falling from the top of the screen needing to fall further to meet the new "top" of the column (I hope that makes sense).

**End Update**

I hope all of the above makes sense to someone with more SpriteKit experience than myself, here is the code for the scene I am currently using. In the code below the showBrick() function needs to be called on a repeating timer.

```
import SpriteKit

internal class GameScene: SKScene {

    private var i: UInt8 = 0

    private let maximumNumberOfRows = 10

    lazy var brickSize: CGSize = {
        return CGSizeMake(self.size.width / 4.0, self.size.height / CGFloat(self.maximumNumberOfRows))
    }()

    lazy var minimumBrickPositionX: CGFloat = {
        return self.brickSize.width * 0.5
    }()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        super.didMoveToView(view)
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeFromPoint: CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0), toPoint: CGPointMake(self.size.width, 0.0))
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: -4.9)//-9.8)
    }

    internal func showBrick() {

        let brick = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.orangeColor(), size: self.brickSize)

        brick.position = CGPointMake(self.minimumBrickPositionX + self.brickSize.width * CGFloat(i++), self.size.height - brickSize.height / 2.0)

        // Arbitrary smaller width than the actual brick size
        // to ensure bricks don't collide with adjacent bricks
        let brickPhysicsBodyWidth = self.brickSize.width - 10.0

        brick.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(brickPhysicsBodyWidth, self.brickSize.height))
        brick.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        brick.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true

        if i >= 4 {
            i = 0
        }

        self.addChild(brick)

    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```